# Closure proof by a subfield

Tags: field-theory

I have to show that the subset $L \subseteq \mathbb{K} $ of the field
$$ \mathbb{K} := (\mathbb{K},+,*,0,1) $$

$*$ stands for multiplication

is a subfield of it. Which means that $L$ is a field.

I know that $L$ has at least to elements and that the following property is satisfied for every $ x,y,z \in L$
$$(x-y)z^{-1} \in L$$

My attempts so far:

Splitting $L$ into two objects and proving that $L$ with multiplication and $1$ is a monoid.
$L$ with addition and $0$ is a abelian group. As a part of doing that one can conclude that the commutativity associativity and distributivity are being inherited from $ \mathbb{K}$.

The closure however is not being inherited and must be proven, the question is how?

I thought about showing through substitution that every product $xz,xy,yz \in L$ but am now sure that it is rigorous enough.

Comment: Prove that $0\in L$ then $1\in L$, then $x^{-1}\in L$ for $x\in L$ then $-x\in L$, then ... and with small steps you get to $x+y\in L$ and $xy\in L$ for $x,y\in L$ and you're done.

Comment: I already showed the first properties that you mentioned. Do you mean that I can show with $y = 0$  and $z^{-1} = y \implies (x-0)y = xy \in L$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your comment above, Ozk, writing it that way runs into problems since $y = 0$ and $z^{-1}=y$ here would imply $z^{-1} = 0$ and all you've done is prove $0 \in L$.

As you have already shown the other properties and are trying to prove additive closure, substitute $-y$ for $y$ and $z = 1$ so that $(x-y)z^{-1}=x+y\in L$.

For multiplicative closure, since $z^{-1} \in L$, one can substitute into the given expression with $y = 0$ and $z^{-1}$ for $z$ so that $(x-y)z^{-1} = x(z^{-1})^{-1}=xz \in L$ for every $x,z \in L$.

Comment: @Derek_Luna Alright, thank you :)

Comment: @Derek_Luna one more thing. In order to show that every element of L can be multiplicative inverted, do I have to show that the product of this element with another element gives the inverse of the original?

Comment: By the expression you have given us, simply take $x = 1$ and $y = 0$ so that for every $z , z^{-1} \in L$. We are not required to show anything else for this. Does that help?

Comment: @Derek_Luna I did exactly that but it shows only that the inverse of an element is also in L, doesn't it? When one wants to show that an element can be multiplicative inverted it has to do with the multiplication, hasn't it?

Comment: $z^{-1}$ means the multiplicative inverse of $z$, that is, the element $x$ such that $z\cdot x=1$ where $\cdot$ is the multiplicative operation in $L$. We did not have to explicitly use multiplication in the argument since the expression you were given already conveniently contained an inverted element.